# How to create new urls based on string pattern

Tags: r, string

```
df <- data.frame(url c("https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t119532-s0.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c34e8a20217",
      "https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t119532-s50.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c34e8a20217",
      "https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t119532-s60.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c34e8a20217",
      "https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t119532-s70.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c34e8a20217","https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t143332-s0.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c34e8a20217",
      "https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t143332-s30.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c34e8a20217"),
    page_id=c("0","50","60","70","0","30"))
```

I have a set of URLs with subpages. The subpages follow a pattern s-0 is the first subpage s-10 is the second, then s-20, s-30, and so on. URLs with many subpages I only have the first and last subpage numbers. For example, I might have s-0 and s-70 but not s-10 through s-60. What I want is to have the subpage identifier for every URL.

From the data frame above, for example, I would like to retrieve

```
df <- data.frame(url = c("https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t119532-s0.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c34e8a20217",
"https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t119532-s10.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c34e8a20217"),
"https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t119532-s0.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c34e8a20217",
"https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t119532-s30.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c34e8a20217",
"https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t119532-s40.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c34e8a20217",
"https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t119532-s50.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c34e8a20217",
"https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t119532-s60.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c34e8a20217",
"https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t119532-s70.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c34e8a20217",
"https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t143332-s0.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c34e8a20217",
"https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t143332-s10.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c34e8a20217",
"https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t143332-s20.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c34e8a20217",
      "https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t143332-s30.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c34e8a20217"),
page_id=c("0","10","20","30","40","50","60","70","0","10","20","30"))
```

I have separated out the end of the URL and created a column with the largest subpage identifier, but I’m not sure where else to go.

Comment: Neither of your code snippets above are valid R syntax. Please fix them. In both, you already have a page id column.. Are you trying to generate that column?  What do you have now, and what are you trying to produce?

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to split the page id and other url components into separate columns with `tidyr::extract()`; fill in intervening page ids using `tidyr::full_seq()` within a grouped summary; then `tidyr::unite()` the columns back together.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  extract(
    url, 
    into = c("url1", "page_id", "url2"),
    "(.+-s)(\\d+)(\\.html.*)"
  ) %>%
  group_by(url1, url2) %>%
  summarize(page_id = full_seq(as.numeric(page_id), 10), .groups = "drop") %>%
  unite("url", url1, page_id, url2, sep = "")
```

```
# A tibble: 12 × 1
   url                                                                          
   <chr>                                                                        
 1 https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t119532-s0.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c3…
 2 https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t119532-s10.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c…
 3 https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t119532-s20.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c…
 4 https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t119532-s30.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c…
 5 https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t119532-s40.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c…
 6 https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t119532-s50.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c…
 7 https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t119532-s60.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c…
 8 https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t119532-s70.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c…
 9 https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t143332-s0.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c3…
10 https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t143332-s10.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c…
11 https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t143332-s20.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c…
12 https://tapatalk.com/groups/thee-t143332-s30.html?sid=674002291c431ba23dd69c…
```

Comment: The problem is that the page id is variable for each URL so some urls go up to 140, etc.

Comment: Can you edit your example to make it clearer what the data will initially look like?

Comment: yup edited! let me know fi that is clear

Comment: Thanks, see my edited answer. It will work whether or not your dataframe already has a `page_id` column.